# Why textarea is showing old content on form submition?

Tags: php

I have a textarea and I can update its content, then I send it to db when I click a submit button:

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="myForm" autocomplete="off">
  <textarea  name="newContent" class="form-control" rows="10"><?php the_content(); ?></textarea>
  <input id="update_content" name="subContent" type="submit" value="Update">
</form>

<?php
    $post = array(
        'ID' => $id,
        'post_content' => $_POST['newContent']
    );
    if ('Update' === ($_POST['subContent'] ?? false)) {
        wp_update_post($post, true); 
    }
?>
```

It all works absolutely fine, db is updated. Yet as the page reloads on form submit, the textarea shows the old content. If I manually refresh the page, then I see the new content.

I've also tried adding      `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">`

Comment: you need to update *before* you output your form. `update code -> form`, not `form -> update code`

Comment: @Sean but  `wp_update_post($post, true); ` is used to update the db, why should I use it before too?

Comment: I understand that `wp_update_post($post, true);` updates the db. but that code needs to be **before** you output your form. so it should be `... wp_update_post($post, true); ...` then `the_content();`. This is why your textarea shows the old code, as it is pull from the db **before** you update/change it, and why you have to manually refresh the page.

Comment: @Sean that's not how it is working. I manually update the page to test, not tech reason apart from checking the caching. Which is what it is happening.  `wp_update_post($post, true);` is used to `SEND` the form content to the db, not `READ`. You can see I have some `conditionals` in the code in the question which sends

Comment: is `<textarea  name="newContent" class="form-control" rows="10"><?php the_content(); ?></textarea>` **before** OR **after** `wp_update_post($post, true);` in your code?? if the textarea is **before**, that is your problem. You need to have the update happen before you have `the_content();` pull the data.

Comment: @Sean ok for the sake of it, I did what you suggested and it is exactly the same thing...

Comment: The problem could be in `the_content()` since as you've mentioned a refresh gets the correct data so you'll have to check how the data is processed in that function.

Comment: @hungrykoala when I first load the page, i get the correct content, if I then submit the new one, it gets inserted in the db correctly, but when then page refreshes on the submit, the textarea shows the old one...if i manually refresh again to check it, then i get the new one..

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant that when you submitted the form you get the old data on refresh so it would seem that the data was processed after this inside `the_content()`

Comment: @hungrykoala yeh i understand what you're saying, it is what Sean said just before you but I did place the update function before and it is the same..

Comment: no I mean check the inside of `the_content()` on how it's processing the data. Would be better if you can show the code inside that function.

Comment: @hungrykoala https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/